# Google-cloud-messaging deploy Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I followed the guide for Google CLoud Messaging and it works perfectly with .\gradlew.bat run -Pmsg="" (GCM Start Guide)

Now I would like to deploy to appengine but I don't know how to do . There is an manual where I can to do it ?

or how I can to do the webserver to send a message ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you can download the app engine program then run a local server using the program and finally you can deploy it to your to your google developers console .

choose your server langauge and follow the guide
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs

I haven't tried to deploy my own application but I plan to do so using what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I did my GCM with  :

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints

I had some error with dependences when I was deploying to appengine ( I changed the version of any library and I deleted test nespresso)  and it works perefectly.